# WP REST API how to check header method

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'd like to check whether the request coming in is a POST, PUT, DELETE or GET. I should note I'm testing on Postman. I can't seem the find the info in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register a route - you define a method to it like GET, POST... plus a callback function. You can have different callback functions for different request types:

```
register_rest_route($namespace,
    array(
        array(
            'methods'   => 'GET',
            'callback'  => 'my_get_something_handler'
        )
    ),
);
```

Alternatively you can have one callback function for all methods, and then within the function use `$request->get_method()` method to check it that was POST, GET.. Here you can find more about the [get_method() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/get_method/)